# Help me with Data Visualization

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, data-visualization, pie-chart

I want to basically output the list of processes the system is running along with the memory consumption of the process into a pie chart.

I have looked at the Pie Series control in WPF but I don't know how it works, I set it's binding to an observable collection but nothing is output.

Can anyone guide me here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is nice article by "Colin Eberhardt" in Code Project. I think it will match your requirement. You can customize it.

[PieChart](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PieChartDataBinding.aspx)